# Vuex (Flux) pattern: Which type of data should be stored in it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, flux

I'm creating an application and using Vuex for the first time.
This application is built in Vue.js and is complex enough to need a singleton storage object, shared between all components. Vuex seems a good solution, but I'm still not sure about which data to store on my vue instance/components and which to store in Vuex.

As per Vuex documentation, it stores 'state data'. By terminology I assume state is just data that represent the current state of the application itself, such as these:

```
{
    isUserLoggedIn: true,
    isPaymentModalShowing: false,
    isLeftMenuOpen: true,
    ....
}
```

Basically, everything that can start with the verb "is" (defining 'state')

This won't really solve my problem, since I'm using a singleton store to provide data access to all my components, having data that do not only represent 'state' of the application but also user data, such as:

```
{
  userData:{
    email: "test@test.com",
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 28
 }
}
```

So my question is pretty straightforward, although I'm not sure there is a straightforward answer: which type of data should I keep on the Vuex store object, and which type of data should I keep on the component or application object?

Comment: The purpose of Vuex is to provide reactivity for data that is shared between Vue Components. In that sense everything that multiple components want to react upon is state that could be added to Vuex. The component would have the state that is specific to than single component. If the data does not change such as your user object, then it might be better placed in an object that gets imported by your components.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main purposes of Vuex is to be **single source of truth** for the application. It means that it should definitely hold information that is **used in multiple places**.

Additionally, Vuex holds not only application state, but all the relevant data - you can have separate modules for UI and User, and Cars.
As a rule of thumb: if you use data in multiple places - store it in Vuex. If data used in one place - you can do without the state in Vuex and live with component-state.

More info: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/should-i-store-this-data-in-vuex/